# SVN connector JavaHL not loads

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, centos, subversive

I have error native `javahl 0x00100000: Cannot load libraries: Could not initialize class org.apache.subversion.javahl.SVNClient` while setting Eclipse connector to SVN on my 32bit CentOS 6.9 :

[image]

I did:

```
yum install subversion-javahl
```

Libs located in `/usr/lib`

```
ls -la /usr/lib/libsvnjavahl* 
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   1040 Aug 17  2015 /usr/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.la
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     23 Feb 12 01:44 /usr/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.so -> libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     23 Feb 12 01:44 /usr/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0 -> libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 240112 Aug 17  2015 /usr/lib/libsvnjavahl-1.so.0.0.0
```

Have added line below `-vmargs` in eclipse.ini

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib
```

System restart.

Where might be problem?

Comment: Would a SVNKit connector (which is 100% implemented in Java without platform-dependent libraries) be an alternative for your JavaHL connector?

Comment: Can I use it with Subversive plugin?

Comment: Yes, see https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive

Comment: I found install link for Neon: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/neon-site/  Is it Ok for my Oxygen2 ?

Comment: Yes, it should also work with Oxygen.2.

Comment: You solved my problem! I'm ready to accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the JavaHL connector, you can use the **SVNKit connector** which is 100% implemented in Java and does not depend on platform-dependent libraries (see also [Subversive – Subversion Team Provider for Eclipse](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive)).

The SVNKit connector can be installed via following update site (which works for Eclipse Neon, Eclipse Oxygen and probably also for future versions):

```
http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/neon-site/
```

Comment: svnkit is kind of buggy, I'd recommend JavaHL when possible.

Comment: @bahrep Can you be more specific? For me Subversive works with SVNKit without problems.

Comment: After trying to make Subversive work with javahl on RHEL7 with Oxygen.2 I still getting the "Cannot load library" error. I switched to the SVNKit connector and Subversive works for me now.